# Toggle instead of Hover function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to repeat the same process everytime I click on the class specified in the code. It was working on hover function but when I switched to click function, it does the job one time only. and it's not repeatable.

Also I switched to clickToggle and it does not work. Any thoughts?

```
var sidebarFloat = $('.sidebar').css('float');
$('.sidebar').hover(function() {
    sidebarFloat = $(this).css('float');

    if (sidebarFloat == 'right') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500)
    } else if (sidebarFloat == 'left') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500)
    }
}, function() {
    var width = $(this).width() - 10;
    if (sidebarFloat == 'right') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: +width
        }, 500);

    } else if (sidebarFloat == 'left') {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: -width
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe create a jsfiddle?

Comment: what jsfiddle is needed for? I pasted the code already. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function takes two functions as parameters: handleIn and HandleOut.

[Click does not.](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

As a result you will have to track the state of the click using a separate variable.

For example:

```
var sidebarFloat = $('.sidebar').css('float');
var toggled = false;
$('.sidebar').click(function() {
    if (toggled) {
        sidebarFloat = $(this).css('float');
        if (sidebarFloat == 'right') {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500)
        } else if (sidebarFloat == 'left') {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500)
        }
    } else {
        var width = $(this).width() - 10;
        if (sidebarFloat == 'right') {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: +width
            }, 500);

        } else if (sidebarFloat == 'left') {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: -width
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    toggled = !toggled;
});
```

Comment: but you still have the hover function instead of a click.

Comment: Whooops. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: if the variable doesn't work, you could potnentially use .data('toggled',true) on the object instead.